# Bitbucket pipelines react mobx @inject failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, mobx, bitbucket-pipelines

React and mobx annotations are working well on local but fail on the bitbucket pipeline.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Compare your local and ci nodejs versions. Is there a mismatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `REACT_APP_DECORATORS=true` to my .env file